# How to get Image using opencv as input for C++ program

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, visual-studio-code

i made a code for solving soduko and now i want to convert sudoku of real life to digital grid using opencv. But i can't import libraries in vscode 2019. Plz help. i get include error

i can't find anywhere how to get it to work. I dont want to work in visual basic but just c++ file

```cpp
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
```

so i get import errors on these and i can't find where to import it. I added to Path the opencv bin folder

Comment: add the error messages, please

Comment: the error message is simply import errors. For example when i use #include<std/bits/.h> it dosent give error coz it knows where the STL libraries are included but when i installed the opencv library and added to Path it dosent recogonise it. Also i have a doubt that can i use these libraries without making a project in a single c++ file ?

Comment: just add the error message... If the header can't be found, add the include directory to your project setting somwhere like project->C/C++->AdditionalIncludeDirectories

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62616960/176769